# Back button doesn't change the url when state changed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using "stateChangeStart" in order to refresh the informations of the connected user .
In the callback, there is a state.go with the url.name (asked state), the parameters and some options.
It work like a charm.

However, when I use the back button, the previous state is displayed but the url doesn't change.

```
Options are:
$retry:false
inherit:true
location:false
notify:true
relative:null
reload:false
```

Here the link to the Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qRmnmlg1euyWrpvze6nD?p=preview

You have to go to home, home.foo and home.foo.detail for example.
Next, you have to try to back to the previous view then, The view is changed but not the url !

Do you have some suggestions ?